# How do I get my Marksdwarves to reload?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In Dwarf Fortress, once my marksdwarves have fired off all of their bolts, is there a way to get them to reload?

Comment: Do you have bolts in an ammo stockpile? Have you assigned your squad to use those bolts via the military screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd prefer your marksdwarves to reload instead of going into melee combat, you can go the military menu, view their squad, and then toggle c to tell them to stay close to their station. This will cause them to go and collect bolts, then start shooting again.

Comment: Doesn't work in DF2010.